# What is VS code Keyboard shortcut to open a peeked file into a tab

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

When I press f12 on a method there is a peeked editor(default setting for Go to Definition is peek in visual studio code) showing the code. We can open that code into new tab by click on peeked file name. Is there any keyboard shortcut to do it without using mouse ?

Note: What I am looking is quite similar to "Promote the definition window to a regular document tab" in Visual Studio. In Visual Studio after Alt+F12 there will be a Peeked Editor showing definition of symbol. When you press Ctrl+Alt+Home, it would open the file into a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Enter key is the keyboard shortcut to open the peeked editor file into new tab. If Ctrl+Enter pressed it would open a vertically Splited Tab